# iOS open Google Maps App to show route with multiple points

Tags: ios, google-maps

How to display route with multiple points? Instead of opening Google Maps and simply showing navigation from point A to point B, I would like to show navigation from point A to B to C to D, etc...

From official documentation it seems I can only specify starting point `saddr` and destination `daddr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/<lat>,<lng>/<lat>,<lng>/.../.../")!)
```

Although it supports up to 23 points